# Expresión regular para url

Tags: php, regex

Necesito una expresión regular que me valide estos tipos de url:

> /prueba/ABC-DEF/2016-11-14+2016-11-29/1-0-0
>
> /prueba/GHI-JKL/2016-11-14/MNJ-HJK/2016-11-29/1-0-0

No he podido que una expresión me valide este caracter "/"

Comment: ¿Que valide que los tenga?

Comment: @Jorgesys Que me valide como tal que la url que ingreso sea de esa forma separada por /

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que has intentado, cuál te ha funcionado y cuál no? Con esos dos ejemplos no sé a qué se refiere con `GHI-JKL` o `MNJ-HJK`, ¿deben ser caracteres consecutivos? ¿esos exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar las siguientes expresiones regulares que ya revise y matchean con tus textos

```
<script>
  var texto = "/prueba/ABC-DEF/2016-11-14+2016-11-29/1-0-0";
  var patron = /\/prueba\/[A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\/\d\-\d-\d/;
  console.log(texto.match(patron));
</script>
```

Este es el segundo patrón:

```
<script>
  var texto = "/prueba/GHI-JKL/2016-11-14/MNJ-HJK/2016-11-29/1-0-0";
  var patron = /\/prueba\/[A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\/[A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\/\d(\-\d){2}/;
  console.log(texto.match(patron));
</script>
```

Este es el patrón donde uno ambos:

```
<script>
  var texto = "/prueba/ABC-DEF/2016-11-14+2016-11-29/1-0-0";
  var texto2 = "/prueba/GHI-JKL/2016-11-14/MNJ-HJK/2016-11-29/1-0-0"
  var patron = var patron = /\/prueba\/[A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3}\/\d{4}(\-\d{2}){2}(\+|\/[A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3}\/)\d{4}(\-\d{2}){2}\/\d(\-\d){2}/;
  console.log(texto.match(patron));
  console.log(texto2.match(patron));
</script>
```

Como puedes ver están ambos textos y compruebo que pase la expresión regular.
Espero que resuelvas con esto. Saludos. Si necesitas que te explique mejor las expresiones regulares que usé dejamelo saber. De primera instancia verifica que resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Si deseas que busque exactamente por un texto con el mismo valor debes poner **^** al comienzo del patrón y **$** al terminar entre **/** **/**

Comment: Además, ¿qué te hace pensar que sólo pueden ir 3 letras mayúsculas separadas por guión, o que sólo pueda aceptar dígitos al final? Deberías esperar a que el autor de la pregunta aclare qué está buscando antes de responder.

Comment: Osea me da dos cadenas que terminan en 3 numeros y debo espera a que el me diga literalmente que terminan asi. Uff k pereza

Comment: No hay nada que indique que quiera que sean números, o quizás quiere que terminen siempre con el literal `"1-0-0"`, o quizás quiere validar que sea una fecha válida y no cualquier número, o quizás también quiera permitir minúsculas... No lo sabemos y por eso hace falta que el autor lo aclare... Ese es el motivo por el cual se cerró la pregunta. Respuestas que intentan adivinar qué está preguntando sólo fomentan que haya más preguntas mal hechas, por eso es que sería recomendable que en estos casos esperes a la aclaración antes de intentar adivinar.

Comment: Todas las preguntas de [TAG:regex] deben cumplir con los 5 puntos solicitados en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: OKOK ya tome nota.